# Use .axd to retrieve variables from global resourse.resx

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I use **webresource.axd** (or other **.axd**) to retrieve variables from global **resource.resx**?
I know the way to retrieve embedded files use **webresource.axd**, but is there any way to retrieve from **.resx** files?

Answer (score 1):

A .resx resource file is generally just an XML file.

To retrieve the names and values of the resources in a .resx file, you should use the [`ResXResourceReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resxresourcereader.aspx) class.

```
// create a ResXResourceReader for the file items.resx
ResXResourceReader rsxr = new ResXResourceReader("items.resx");

// iterate through the resources and display the contents to the console
foreach (DictionaryEntry d in rsxr)
{
    Console.WriteLine(d.Key.ToString() + ":\t" + d.Value.ToString());
}

// close the reader
rsxr.Close();
```

Hope that helps!